# Detect touch position on UiScrollView

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview, touch

I need to get the touch position from a UIScrollView. But when I create a subclass for my scrollview :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
  UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touchesArray objectAtIndex:0];
  CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
  self.position = point;}
```

The function `touchesBegan` isn't always called. 
If I swipe fast, `touchesBegan` is never called, but `scrollViewDidScroll` gets directly called instead.

I can't use `UIGesture (UITapGestureRecognizer, ... )` because users don't tap or swipe.

Are there others methods to get the position from UIScrollView ?

**EDIT :**

Thanks ThXou : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15763450/1752843

UIScrollView subclass :

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    self.position = point;
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668643/1257854) in SO that I think that it can solve you problem. It seems that the SDK doesn't pass the touch handling methods to the UIScrollView subclasses anymore. So, you should to perform a `hitTest:` to pass the touches to your subclass.

See the answer for more information.

Comment: Thx! My code : '- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    
    self.position = point;
    
    return self;
}'

Answer (score 7):

To detect the touch location inside scrollview, try this code

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap]; 

- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
 { 
   CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scrollView];
 }
```

Comment: But the function "touchesBegan" or "touchesMoved" are never called when my scrollview is scrolled. And I want to get the touch when my scrollview is used.

Comment: Even though "touchesBegan" is empty, her are never called.

Comment: Sorry try the above code. other method is yu need to call the sub classes . For further details, check out this link http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/detect-single-tap-in-uiscrollview.html

Comment: To detect touchesBegan and touchesMoved, sub-classing is NOT required. You can add the UIScrollViewDelegate to the "h" file and applicable functions to detect touches based on user intention. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993280/how-to-detect-when-a-uiscrollview-has-finished-scrolling/20017639#20017639

Answer (score 3):

You could alternatively use `scrollview.panGestureRecognizer`'s  `locationInView` method to get the coordinates of a touch in your view. This could be in any of `scrollView`'s delegate method depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

It will makes that touchesBegan and other touch events will be triggered before scrollViewDidScroll.

The hitTest is a hack and should not be preferred solution.